# How to limit minimum dimensions of cropper in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-capture

I want to restrict the user to crop the image to an image of **`200 x 200`** or some other value. i.e. while cropping, if the cropper has reached its minimum limit defined by me , it should stop squeezing inward. Can any one guide me how can i do this.

Some extras that m using for cropping are :

```
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("scale", true);

intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

intent.putExtra("outputX", 600);
intent.putExtra("outputY",  600);
```

[image]

Comment: are you using any Third party lib or your own code ?

Comment: @NadirB m using my own code. just invoking default cropper.